# CV2 object detection python to C++

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm trying to create a detection which will click on the object of the defined color using cv2. But detection in python is very slow, how would the code be in c++ and how impactful is the difference between one and the other

```
import cv2
import dxcam
import numpy as np
from win32api import GetAsyncKeyState
import serial

fov = 38
xspd = 1
yspd = 1

# Detect yellow objects
lower = np.array([30, 160, 240])
upper = np.array([30, 255, 255])

arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200)
center = fov/2
camera = dxcam.create(device_idx= 0, output_color= "BGRA")
left, top = (1920 - fov) // 2, (1080 - fov) // 2
right, bottom = left + fov, top + fov
region = (left, top, right, bottom)

camera.start(region=(region), target_fps=144)

# Click in objects
def mousemove(x,y):
        data = f"{int(x)}:{int(y-2.8)}"
        arduino.write(data.encode())

while True:
    img = camera.get_latest_frame()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower,upper)
    kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
    dilated = cv2.dilate(mask,kernel,iterations= 5)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(dilated, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    if len(contours) != 0:
        M = cv2.moments(thresh)
        # Centroid
        point_to_aim = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), (int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])))
        closestX = int(point_to_aim[0] - center) * xspd
        closestY = int((point_to_aim[1])  - center) * xspd
        mousemove(closestX, closestY)
```

If it is possible to do the conversion to c++ and some explanation if the detection speed really improves with c++.

Comment: wrong question. all OpenCV routines are written in C++ and compiled. they'll run the same, no matter what language they're called from. -- if your code is slow, figure out **what parts of it** are slow. **profile** your code. python comes with profilers.

Comment: What if you change this target_fps=144 to target_fps=120?

Comment: I had like this target_fps = 120
camera = dxcam.create(output_idx=0, output_color="BGR")
camera.start(target_fps=target_fps, video_mode=True)

Comment: As I don't have nvidia cards with cuda cores I ended up opting for multiprocessing, and thus made the program much faster and with better detection.